# The intersection of all curves is the intersection of a finite number of curves

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, noetherian, polynomial-rings

let $f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),\dots{}$  be an infinitely countable number of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Denote by $C_n$ the curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$
C_n = \bigl\{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid f_n(a,b) = 0 \bigr\}.
$$

If $C$ is the intersection of all curves, that is,$$ C= \bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}C_n$$
prove that there exists $m\geq1$ such that
$$
C = \bigcap^{m}_{n=1}C_n,
$$
this is the intersection of a finite number of curves.

I think we can use Hilberts Basis Theorem, but I can't think of how to start the argument. Could you help me, please!

Hilbert's basis theorem says that a polynomial ring over a Noetherian ring is Noetherian.

Comment: Your thought is a good one. *Keep going!* How is the property of being Noetherian useful? Can you construct an ascending chain of ideals that is somehow related to this family of curves?

Comment: I thought about the ideals generated by the $f_{i}$, does it make any sense?

Comment: How do you make the ideals form an ascending chain $I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq \cdots$ though?

Comment: it could be $(f_1) \subset(f_1,f_2) \subset \dots $, where $(f_1)$ is 
is the generating ideal by $f_1$? Since $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is noetherian, the chain is stationary. From there, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing the argument of comments, let us consider the chain
$$(f_1)\subset (f_1,f_2)\subset\cdots$$
which is stationary, say, at $(f_1,\dots,f_m)$.
That is, $f_j\in (f_1,\dots,f_m)$ and
$$f_j=a_1^{(j)}f_1+\cdots+a_m^{(j)}f_m\quad (*)$$
holds for all $j=m+1,m+2,\cdots$.
Now, for the intersection,
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n\subset \bigcap_{n=1}^m C_n$$
holds trivially. The converse also holds since if $(x,y)$ is in RHS then by the relation $(*)$ it automatically satisfy $f_j(x,y)=0\ (j=m+1,m+2,\dots )$, hence it is in LHS, too.